# Bind data from one control to another

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm using LightSwitch 2011 with Visual Studio 2010, I'm aware that you can change Visibility of Controls with this code:

```
this.FindControl("Example_Of_Control").IsVisible = False;
```

However, what I want instead is to assign the value, something like this:

```
this.FindControl("Example_Of_Control").Value = "Some text";
```

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

The *FindControl* method only returns a *proxy* for the control. The *proxy* only has a limited number of properties that you can read/write.

You actualy shouldn't be trying to set the value of a **control** at all, you should just assign the value to the **property** that the control is **bound** to.

In a LightSwitch screen each control **must** be bound to a property. So you might have a *TextBox* that's bound to an entity's *Price* property. Instead of trying to set the value to a property of the *TextBox*, you should assign the value directly to the *Price* property instead. Because the *TextBox* is **bound** to the *Price* property, the control will display the newly assigned value.